# "Add Event Handler" option is grayed out in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I needed to recompile an old MFC project (originally written with VS 2003.) The latest version of Visual Studio that I can open it with (to adhere to the specs for a compiled executable) is VS 2008.

So after conversion, all class wizard options for working with messages/notifications/events are grayed out. Here's an example:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

PS. I understand that I can add those events manually. It just takes longer. So I thought to have it fixed first.

PS2. [*Suggested Edit*] An MFC project created using the New Project wizard in VS 2008 supports the functionality.

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while) the wizard used comments to recognise where to add the code.  Try creating a new project and see if the comments / boilerplate code match your ported project.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Thanks. Just tried it. There's too many of them. It'd be nice to know which ones it's missing.

Comment: Just a wild guess: The [MFC Class Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-class-wizard) returned in Visual Studio 2010, that provides adding message handlers (among others). Maybe VS 2008 simply doesn't support the feature (but carried over the menu entry from VS 6).

Comment: @IInspectable: No. Otherwise it wouldn't work in a boilerplate/empty MFC template project.

Comment: Richard is right. It has something to do with comments. Unfortunately the only [reference I can find](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?429629-What-makes-the-Event-Handler-Wizard-greyed-out) provides very little in the sense of usability. The OP evidently _"figured it out"_ but forgot to sensibly explain where.

Comment: That's an important detail. Maybe you should edit your question to include, that a project created using the New Project wizard in VS 2008 supports the functionality.

Comment: @IInspectable: Good point. Just did it.

Comment: It looks like you are right clicking an item above another. Is it really a new item and there is no even handler for it? _Add Event Handler_ will be grayed if VS detects an existing handler. Search the ID if you are not sure.